View Transitions API in Chrome not applying correct transitions
I am struggling to get the View Transitions API to behave as intended. My guess is that I'm missing something simple. This is a very basic implementation within a single page.
I am showing three blocks on-screen, and swapping the middle block in and out from <template> content. My expectation is that the content I am swapping with the name view-transition-name "block-trans" will have the transition animation applied, and that the other blocks will move smoothly out of the way. In reality, all elements fade out and back in with the default transition.
Abbreviated code below. Example CodePen here.
My assumption was that this would be similar to this example, which, of course, does work.
HTML:
<template id="view1">
    <div class="block block-trans" view-transition-name="block-trans">
        View 1
        <button onclick="swap('template#view2', '.block-trans')">Go to View 2</button>
    </div>
</template>
<template id="view2">
    <div class="block block-trans" view-transition-name="block-trans">
        View 2
        <button onclick="swap('template#view1', '.block-trans')">Go to View 1</button>
    </div>
</template>

<div class="content">
    <div class="block block1" view-transition-name="e1">Test block</div>
    
    <div class="block block-trans" view-transition-name="block-trans">
        View 1
        <button onclick="swap('template#view2', '.block-trans')">Go to View 2</button>
    </div>

    <div class="block block1" view-transition-name="e1">Test block</div>
</div>

JS:
function swap(inTemplSelector, outSelector) {
    let inTempl = document.querySelector(inTemplSelector);
    let inEl = inTempl.content.cloneNode(true).firstElementChild;
    let outEl = document.querySelector(outSelector);

    if (document.startViewTransition) {
        document.startViewTransition(() => {
            outEl.replaceWith(inEl);
        });
    }
    else outEl.replaceWith(inEl);
}

CSS:
::view-transition-old(block-trans),
::view-transition-new(block-trans) {
    animation: .3s transition 0s ease;
}

@keyframes transition{
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        translate: 0;
        rotate: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        translate: 1rem -5rem;
        rotate: 8deg;
    }
}


My question is apparently two separate problems, and I've found an update that fixes both problems. Using view-transition-name in the CSS instead of the markup fixes both the fallback to default animations for block-trans AND setting on each of the non-transitioning blocks allows them to fluidly move out of the way of the incoming block. Working example here
Strangely, the example in my original post that I was copying from DOES work, even when copied from CodePen and run locally. Why is that?

Ah -- I see. The other example is using inline styles: style="view-transition-name: item-0". I guess I missed that because I'm so unused to devs setting inline styles.

I was ignoring that examples were setting view-transition-name as an inline style rather than an HTML element attribute.
Setting view-transition-name in your CSS will fix the issue, and providing a unique view-transition-name for each element (except the one you're swapping) will ensure that the surrounding elements are properly FLIP'd. See working example here.
